# Facebook marketplace track webpage changes

Tags: facebook, search, web-scraping, monitor, marketplace

I want to find a way to track fb marketplace searches. I have tried using distill.io successfully on other sites but it fails with facebook.

I posed the question to distill support who told me facebook marketplace updates regularly and autogenerated selectors wont work and would have to hand coded.

I have tried looking at this but am not versed in css and cant see how I can go about manually doing this.

Is there another app or method for me to monitor the marketplace otherwise?

Thanks

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. And they don't have an API for marketplace yet

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will only refresh the marketplace page and filter by most recently posted if you change things like max and min price. This code opens random facebook links with carious prices for my desired price range category.

This only works if you add the numer that you have on your url when you sign in to market place. For example use:

'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/vehicles?maxPrice=10000&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false'

Then change the max and min prices in the url to random numbers near you desired range. You will need to manually refresh by clicking this button every few minutes.

My problem now is getting alerts through distill.io using a method like this that generates random links. Does anyone know how I could set up alerts based on the change in text for the most recently posted items?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Facebook Refresh</h1>

<p>Click the button to trigger random price change to allow facebook to refresh newest links</p>

<button onclick="randomSite()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var sites = [
        'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/vehicles?minPrice=100&maxPrice=9000&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false',
        'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/vehicles?minPrice=200&maxPrice=8500&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false',
        'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/vehicles?minPrice=200&maxPrice=8501&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false',
        'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/vehicles?minPrice=240&maxPrice=8300&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false',
        'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/vehicles?minPrice=203&maxPrice=9211&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false',
        'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/vehicles?minPrice=204&maxPrice=8600&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false',
        'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/vehicles?minPrice=1065&maxPrice=9000&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false',
        'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/vehicles?minPrice=260&maxPrice=8500&sortBy=creation_time_descend&exact=false',
    
    ];

    function randomSite() {
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
        location.href = sites[i];
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use this for manually refreshing. Does anyone know how it could be implemented into distill.io to refresh and send me notifications on the newest items posted?

Comment: Do consider including an explanation as it would make your answer more useful

Comment: I just added the description. I am new to stack overflow. Thanks!